# Orange "Scatter plot" widget to excel, best way

Tags: orange, excel

So I have chosen "Orange" for my research as a main app for clustering ant it's analysis.

Excel 2016 is primary app used for dashboard (via "pivot table").

Problem - how to add graphs from "scatter plot" to excel dashboard and sync it at certain time? Is there a way?

Orange provided reporting does not help, maybe there is another - more interactive way? because all I can get now is images via hyperlinks, which is not interactive.